# Multiple side-by-side barplots grouped by one numerical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I apologise for asking a simple question but I have tried to find a solution over the last couple of days. There are 8 levels under Sampling.Station.Number in the data frame below. Therefore, I am attempting to produce a side-by-side barplot showing three bars per sampling station for three bat species detected called: (1) Pipestrellus pygmaeus; (2) Pipestrellus pipestrellus; and (3)nyctalus noctula.

Any suggestions how to do that? I made some searches but I only find examples for factors on the x axis, not variables grouped by a numerical variable, any help will be appreciated!

In the end I want to produce a barplot that has the same format as this   boxplot, which I constructed:

[image]

I created these boxplot's with this code below:

```
         Sampling.Station.labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")

         bat.labels<-c("Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula",
                       "Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula",
                       "Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula",
                       "Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula",
                       "Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula",
                       "Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula",
                       "Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula",
                       "Pipistrellus pygmaeus", "Pipestrellus pipestrellus", "Nyctalus noctula")


         data_long <- gather(bats1, x, Mean.Value, Saparano.Pipestrelle:Noctule)
         head(data_long) 

         stacked.data.1<-melt(data_long, id=c('Sampling.Station', 'x'))
         head(stacked.data.1)
         str(stacked.data.1)


         stacked.data.1=stacked.data.1[, -3]
         head(stacked.data.1)
         colnames(stacked.data.1)<-c("Sampling.Station", "Bat.Species", "Light.Intensity") 
         head(stacked.data.1)


         par(mfrow = c(1,1))
         boxplots.double.1=boxplot(Lighty.Intensity~Sampling.Station + Bat.Species, 
                                   data = stacked.data.1, 
                                   at = c(1:24), 
                                   ylim = c(min(0, min(0)), 
                                            max(30, na.rm = T)),
                                   xaxt = "n",
                                   notch=TRUE,
                                   col = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                                   cex.axis=0.7,
                                   cex.labels=0.7,
                                   ylab="Light Intensity (Lux)", 
                                   xlab="Sampling Stations",
                                   space=1)

         axis(side = 1, at = seq(3, 24, by = 1), labels = FALSE)
         text(seq(3, 24, by=3), par("usr")[3] - 0.2, labels=unique(Sampling.Station.labels), srt = 45, pos = 1, xpd = TRUE, cex=0.8)
         par(oma = c(4, 1, 1, 1))
         par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), new = TRUE)
         plot(0, 0, type = "n", bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
         legend("top", 
                legend=c("Pipistrellus pygmaeus","Pipestrellus pipestrellus","Nyctalus noctula"),
                fill=c("Blue", "Red", "Green"),
                xpd = TRUE, horiz = TRUE, 
                inset = c(0,0), 
                bty = "n", 
                col = 1:4, 
                cex = 0.8,
                title = "Bat Species",
                lty = c(1,1))
```

I tried Richard's suggestion but I am still experiencing this error message, would anyone be able to help. Many thanks in advance if this is possible:

```
   data=format

   Data structure: 

   'data.frame':    144 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ Sampling.Station    : num  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
     $ Light.Intensity.S   : num  26.9 25.2 39 29.8 21.8 ...
     $ Number.of.bat.passes: num  3 2 5 6 15 2 10 12 17 2 ...
     $ Bat.Species         : Factor w/ 3 levels       "Common.Pipestrelle",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ Simpsons.Index      : num  0.4444 0 0 0.0278 0 ...

       df %>% 
       gather(key = bat.species, value = value, -station) %>%
       mutate(station = as.factor(station)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = station, y = value, colour = variable)) +
       geom_boxplot() + 
       facet_grid(~bat.species, scales = "free_y")


       **Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Sampling.Station' not found**
```

**Dataframe**

```
bats1<-structure(list(Sampling.Station = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1), Light.Intensity = c(26.9, 25.16, 
39, 29.81, 21.83, 20.22, 2.9, 2.1, 0.85, 0.62, 0.39, 0.26, 24.7, 
21.99, 20.46, 26.32, 0, 0, 0.43, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.03, 
 293.56, 167.79, 114.06, 17.22, 16.26, 4.76, 0.63, 0.56, 0.56, 
 86.63, 87.97, 88.59, 0.31, 0.04, 0.05, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 2.6, 
 2.68, 2.62, 0.43, 0.44, 26.9, 25.16, 39, 29.81, 21.83, 20.22, 
 2.9, 2.1, 0.85, 0.62, 0.39, 0.26, 24.7, 21.99, 20.46, 26.32, 
 0, 0, 0.43, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.03, 293.56, 167.79, 114.06, 
 17.22, 16.26, 4.76, 0.63, 0.56, 0.56, 86.63, 87.97, 88.59, 0.31, 
 0.04, 0.05, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 2.6, 2.68, 2.62, 0.43, 0.44, 
 26.9, 25.16, 39, 29.81, 21.83, 20.22, 2.9, 2.1, 0.85, 0.62, 0.39, 
  0.26, 24.7, 21.99, 20.46, 26.32, 0, 0, 0.43, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 
  0.02, 0.03, 293.56, 167.79, 114.06, 17.22, 16.26, 4.76, 0.63, 
  0.56, 0.56, 86.63, 87.97, 88.59, 0.31, 0.04, 0.05, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 
  0.02, 2.6, 2.68, 2.62, 0.43, 0.44), Number.of.bat.passes = c(3, 
  2, 5, 6, 15, 2, 10, 12, 17, 2, 0, 0, 15, 7, 17, 0, 1, 0, 14, 
  10, 12, 7, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 6, 11, 3, 0, 0, 12, 11, 9, 1, 2, 
  1, 12, 14, 10, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 15, 2, 10, 12, 17, 
  2, 0, 0, 15, 7, 17, 0, 1, 0, 14, 10, 12, 7, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 
  6, 11, 3, 0, 0, 12, 11, 9, 1, 2, 1, 12, 14, 10, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 
  2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 15, 2, 10, 12, 17, 2, 0, 0, 15, 7, 17, 0, 1, 0, 
  14, 10, 12, 7, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 6, 11, 3, 0, 0, 12, 11, 9, 1, 
  2, 1, 12, 14, 10, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2), Bat.Species = structure(c(3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label =           c("Common.Pipestrelle", 
 "Noctule", "Saprano.Pipestrelle"), class = "factor"), Simpsons.Index =           c(0.444444444, 
  0, 0, 0.027777778, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.08650519, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, 
  0, 0.124567474, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.01, 0.111111111, 0.081632653, 
  0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 1, 0.027777778, 0.033057851, 0.111111111, 0, 
  0, 0.027777778, 0.074380165, 0.012345679, 0, 0, 1, 0.173611111, 
  0.081632653, 0.16, 1, 0.25, 0, 0.04, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0, 0, 
  7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.222222222, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, 
  9, 0.5, 1.25, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1.25, 0.888888889, 
  5, 0, 0, 2, 0.28, 0.625, 0.375, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 0.109375, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.046875, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0.046875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, 0.015625, 0, 
  0, 0, 0.28, 0, 0.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names =    c(NA, 
  -144L), .Names = c("Sampling.Station", "Light.Intensity",         "Number.of.bat.passes", 
   "Bat.Species", "Simpsons.Index"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you want the spectrometer  values on the y axis? What do you want to do with the values on D.SP, D.CP and D.N columns? Dont you mean you want those on the y-axis? I'm confused.

Comment: The image shows boxplots, not barplots. What is it that you want?

Comment: use `tidyr::gather` to reshape your data frame, then facet_wrap on the variable name.

Comment: Hi, yes, spectrometer is a series of light intensity measurements taken at eight different point marks within an urban park in dark/light conditions near street lighting to measure the presence or/absence by counts of these three species D.SP, D.CP and D.N under differential light intensity levels.

Comment: Therefore, I would like the x-axis to show eight different sampling stations, from which counts of these three species will be grouped by sampling station. Hence, three bars per sampling station to show counts of these three species D.SP, D.CP and D.N under different light intensity measurements, which should be on the y-axis. Above is an example of a barplot, which I am attempting to emulate. I have used tidyr:gather and I keep on getting error measurements and the bars appear to be the same size for all species. I just cannot wrap my head around this problem.

Comment: But how do you want the variables aggregated? By mean? by sum? Each sampling station includes multiple observations for each of those three variables....

Comment: Sorry Cyrus, Good question. Definitely by the mean. Thank you, it is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are after. This is what I would do with these data. I've used boxplots rather than barcharts as I think the latter are generally fairly useless for displaying variation.

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")

df %>% 
  gather(key = variable, value = value, -Sampling.Station.Number) %>%
  mutate(Sampling.Station.Number = as.factor(Sampling.Station.Number)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sampling.Station.Number, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y")
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Sampling.Station.Number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Spectrometer = c(26.9, 
25.16, 39, 29.81, 21.83, 20.22, 2.9, 2.1, 0.85, 0.62, 0.39, 0.26, 
24.7, 21.99, 20.46, 26.32, 0, 0, 0.43, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 
0.03, 293.56, 167.79, 114.06, 17.22, 16.26, 4.76, 0.63, 0.56, 
0.56, 86.63, 87.97, 88.59, 0.31, 0.04, 0.05, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 
2.6, 2.68, 2.62, 0.43, 0.44), D.SP = c(0.667, 0, 0, 0.167, 0, 
0, 0.5, 0, 0.294, 0, 0, 0, 0.333, 0, 0.353, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.1, 
0.333, 0.286, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 1, 0.167, 0.182, 0.333, 0, 0, 
0.167, 0.273, 0.111, 0, 0, 1, 0.417, 0.286, 0.4, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 
0.5, 0.5), D.CP = c(0.333, 1, 0.4, 1.167, 0.533, 1, 0, 0.167, 
0.118, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.714, 0.471, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.9, 0.667, 0.714, 
1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0, 0.833, 0.727, 0.333, 0, 0, 0.417, 0.727, 
0.556, 1, 1, 2, 0.583, 0.714, 0.6, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5), 
    D.N = c(0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0.467, 0, 0, 0, 0.176, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.286, 0.176, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.091, 0, 0, 0, 0.583, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Sampling.Station.Number", "Spectrometer", 
"D.SP", "D.CP", "D.N"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48"))
```

Comment: Hi Richard,  Thank you so much for getting back to me, and for your suggestion, it was deeply appreciated.. I tried to use your code and got this error message back  **Error: not compatible with STRSXP**.  I changed the factorial column name of x to bat.species and then substituted the bat.species for variable in the code.  However, I still cannot see what I have done wrong. I inputted the structure of my data for the dataset called format (showed above). Any suggestions will be warmly accepted. Thank you again

Comment: In your new code above, you probably want facet_grid not facet_wrap

Comment: `gather(key = bat.species, value = value, -     format$Sampling.Station.Number)` probably won't work as format$Sampling.Station.Number isn't a column in df

Comment: Hey Richard, I used facet_grid and made the necessary changes. I still cannot get the code to work. Would it be possible to please point out what I am doing wrong, I am new to ggplot and still learning, so this exercise is great! I placed the new code with error message above. Thank you

Comment: The data you show and the data you describe do not appear to be the same. station is not a column in df. It is Sampling.Station.Number.

Comment: Hi Richard, I changed the column name Sampling.Station.Number (above) to station for ease. I managed to produce a boxplot showing what I am attempting to achieve (above). I would still like to produce the plot from your code. I am still getting this error message Error: not compatible with STRSXP. Would it be possible to please explain. Thank you :)

Comment: that error is probably coming from the data manipulation. But I don't think the data you present is the same as the data you are using ?light intensity. Run the code one line at a time (without the trailing %>%) to locate the problem. Your line ` station=format$Sampling.Station.Number` will not be noticed by `gather`

Comment: Hi Richard, I placed a new data frame above and I changed the column name Sampling.Stat‌​ion.Number in the original .csv file to Sampling.Station. I ran the code and it still appears not work, so I really do not understand. The error message is saying that the object Sampling.Station cannot be found; however, the column is called Sampling.Station. I placed the structure of the data above. Any ideas.....